# SAS OLE DB connection in Power BI

Tags: sas, oledb, powerbi, oledbconnection

I need to connect `Power BI` to `SAS` using an `OLE DB` connection (can't use `ODBC` nor the native connection). Here is the string from the build:

```
provider=sas.IOMProvider.9.45;data source="iom-name://SASApp - Logical Workspace Server";mode="ReadWrite|Share Deny None";sas cell cache size=10000;sas port=0;sas protocol=0;sas server type=1;sas metadata user id=dxru984;sas metadata password=XXXXX;sas metadata location=iom-bridge://lhwappb1.xxx-xx.xxx:8561
```

I also tried with this one:

```
Provider=sas.IOMProvider.9.45;Data Source=iom-name://SASApp - Logical Workspace Server;SAS Cell Cache Size=10000;SAS Port=0;SAS Protocol=0;SAS Server Type=1;SAS Metadata User ID=dxru984;SAS Metadata Password=xxxxxxx;SAS Metadata Location=iom-bridge://lhwappb1.xxx-xx.xxx:8561
```

The first string works perfectly with `Excel` but not in `PowerBI` with that error message:

> OLE DB : Format of the initialization string does not conform to the
>   OLE DB specification

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect to SAS Federation Server data using the following connection string:

provider=sas.IOMProvider.9.45;data source=blablabla2.abc.pt;sas port=1234;sas protocol=2;sas metadata user id=******;sas metadata password=**********;sas metadata location=blablabla1.abc.pt:5678

Hope this helps,

Rita Dias